# Get index of dictionary item in list by regexp

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary, indexing

I have a list:

```
[
  {
    'avail': 'blabla',
    'rep_main': 'qweqwe',
    ....
  },
  {
    'avail': 'asdasd',
    'rep_main': 'zxczxc',
    ....
  },
  ...
]
```

I want to get the index of the item by means of regexp
That's like a version without regexp:

```
[list['rep_main'] for elem in list].index('qweqwe')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `pattern` is the pattern and `re` is [the `re` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
[i for i, elem in enumerate(mylist) if re.match(pattern, elem['rep_main'])]
```

You can use [`re.search` instead of `re.match`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match).

[`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) is a convenient built-in function that lets you use indexes without that `for i in range(len(mylist))` ugliness.

Note: the expression above obviously evaluates to a list. `.index()` method returns the first matching index. To achieve that, write:

```
next(i for i, elem in enumerate(mylist) if re.match(pattern, elem['rep_main']))
```

Comment: [i for i, elem in enumerate(list) if re.search('qwe$', elem['rep_main'])]

I have the following error:
"TypeError: expected string or buffer"